# GitLab CI Pipeline Job gives error JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gitlab-ci, yarnpkg, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a WordPress plugin written in JS with the help of the tool `wp-reactivate`.

Our goal is to make a GitLab CI Pipeline that increases the version in all places, builds the project and deploys it to the WordPress.org SVN repository. So far, the SVN deployment does work, incrementing the version number is unimplemented yet, but we have a problem building the project. The GitLab CI Runner refuses to finish the process since it ran out of available memory.

[image: The error message]

We have already tried (with no effect):

- Setting `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`
- Setting `NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=8192"`
- Running `node --max-old-space-size=8192`

Our `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

default:
  image: node

BuildApp:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
    - NODE_OPTIONS=\"--max_old_space_size=8192\"
    - node --max-old-space-size=8192
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn prod

PluginSVN:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt-get install subversion
    - curl -o /usr/bin/deploy.sh https://git-cdn.e15r.co/open-source/wp-org-plugin-deploy/raw/master/scripts/deploy.sh
    - chmod +x /usr/bin/deploy.sh
  script: /usr/bin/deploy.sh
  when: on_success
```

Is there any way to increase the amount of available memory, or reduce the amount of memory required for building the project?

Comment: Maybe GitLab is not designed to execute heavy operations, long lasting builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Gitlab Forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/what-are-resource-limits-for-ci-jobs-on-gitlab-com-ram-cpus/29821):
Every runner only have 1CPU, 4GB RAM,

which means you don't have to adjust node options, it won't work.

For me, self-hosted is an option.

Comment: For linux runners: 3.75GB of RAM, 1 vCPU and 25GB of HDD (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html - for gitlab.com v15)

Comment: I got same error when install gitlab-runner on self-host (ec2 instance) directly.

Answer (score 2):

what ever I install gitlab-runner on self host, or docker, I got same issue.

Finally I got the root cause. The ec2 instance I created is too low, **t2.micro**

After I adjust it to **t3.medium** (you should be fine to adjust to any, with 4GB+ memory), it works without this issue any more.